# Is offering jobs to students I'm teaching as a "representative of industry" OK?

Tags: conflict-of-interest, networking

I have a simple question to which I was unable to find a simple answer. I was hired by a university as a "representative of industry" to deliver some courses. In my groups I have several promising students to whom I would like to offer a job after the course ends.

I think this would be OK from students' point of view (the job comes to them, instead of requiring them to spend time in job fairs etc). I think this would also be great from a company's point of view (they can get a student whose abilities and skills they can be reasonably confident in). However, this looks almost too good to be true and I have a feeling that there's some conflict of interest here.

Is such an arrangement common (i.e., hiring *your* students) or is it inappropriate and I should avoid it?

Edit to provide more details: the students are about half-way through their degree and the summer break is slowly appearing on the horizon, so the job would be a limited-term apprenticeship while they do not have any university obligations. The country in question is Poland.

Comment: Are the studemts about to graduate? Or is it a part-time job similar to what many students would have during school anyway?

Comment: You didn't indicate the country, but in the US you should be aware of the rules pertaining to "government owned entities", where offering a job to a relative of someone your company has [an unrelated] business with could land the company, and you, in hot water.

Comment: If this happened in the US when I was a student, I would be all over it. Got a summer internship that turned into 7 years of full time employment in a similar, though not quite as direct a manner.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I agree completely with the others that you should check with your university and your company. Their opinions are the ones that matter. Still, it is quite possible that your institutions will not provide guidance in either direction, so I will not end the answer there.

The only conflict of interest I can see is if you are grading (or otherwise holding authority over) students while simultaneously encouraging them to apply for a job. In this case, students could feel coerced into applying for or accepting a job (or could construe this as a reason if they don't like their grade, etc.). The simplest solution would be to wait until the course ends (and some would say this is your only ethical option). But given that a successful hire is a huge win for all involved, and that hiring is often time-sensitive, you could consider other mitigations, such as having someone else from your company handle the recruitment process, and making it clear to the student that you will intentionally be kept "out of the loop" until the course ends. And of course, be transparent about what you are doing by proactively informing your department chair of your plans (preferably in writing).

Comment: "wait until the course ends"  More precisely, wait until grades are submitted.

Comment: Or maybe you should wait until their graduation. You (or the university) may not want students to drop before completing their full education programme for a tempting job offer that appears to be "supported" by the university because a "teacher" made the offer.

Comment: @Louic at that point, a promising student is liable to already have a job.

Comment: @Tim That strongly depends on the field and the country. But it mostly depends on what the university OP works for wants, as my own answer states.

Comment: @Tim You can extend job offers -- even binding and in writing -- that are dependent on them getting their degree. So if they are promising and you don't want them to get poached, give them an offer that is only valid once they get their degree. And maybe put a time limit on it. Its the best of both worlds, you get a promising employee, encourage them to graduate quickly and they don't get poached. You could even employ them part-time during their studies and offer a full-time position upon graduation, and make that offer in writing long beforehand. its actually quite common where I come from.

Answer (score 23):

You should talk to the university. What they think about it is more important than what "random" people on the internet think.

Comment: +1 . Also, some countries and companies have hiring requirements where jobs need to be posted to the public.

Comment: Yes, working through the university is a must.

Comment: I really dislike these kind of answers. Yes, it's technically correct, but offers absolutely zero insight into the question. The answer from cag51 is far more informative

Comment: OP was literally looking for a "simple answer", I gave him one. There are many factors to consider (some, but not all are outlined in answers below), but in the end the only factors that matter are the ones that said university considerers important.

Comment: To break down the abstract concept of the "university" to talk to: a) your department chair and/or who formally invited you b) your departments or universities ethics commission. At least for the latter, it is exactly their job to answer these questions, and they will be glad to help since you asked before you did anything :)

Comment: @Louic I totally agree with you on that point, but you could choose any random question on this site and chances are good that "talk to the university" would answer it. That would make for a pretty boring website, not to mention that its brevity is edging into sounding dismissive - two things that work against building a strong community. A discussion about the kind of thought processes the university would have can much better prepare someone when they do go to talk to them.

Comment: @Phill In all my other answers I give this level of detail. In this question however, I have not done so deliberately: my interpretation of the statement "unable to find simple answer to simple question" is that OP already searched on the internet, but got confused by the (sometimes contradictory or opinion based) discussions about what a university may or may not like. I therefore avoided these and kept it simple and to the point.

Comment: This answer is not even a good self-fulfilling prophesy. By telling OP to go through the University, you're actually putting them on track to the correct solution. Internet opinions are a good resource, especially if you choose your forum correctly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You are missing two important points here: (1) OP asked for a simple answer, (2) This is the only correct simple answer, because any other answer depends on the university or country. Bottom line: some universities may welcome the job offers, others will oppose them, therefore: do not listen to random people on the internet, but ask *your* university. In my reading of the question, the long discussions about  why a university may or may not like lecturers offering jobs is exactly what led OP to ask a question here.

Comment: We're in violent agreement. My point was that you say not to listen to strangers on the internet, but then you, a stranger on the internet, proceed to give what is essentially the only rational answer in any situation like this: talk to the stakeholders. I was giving you a half-joking backhanded compliment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok, thanks :). I did not get that.

Answer (score 14):

A point missed by the other answers:

The university will be very upset if you hire students into permanent, full time jobs before they graduate.  *Inducing students to leave the university without a degree is irresponsible.*  It is bad for the finances of both the student and the university.  Students with incomplete degrees are usually paid less (correlation, probable causation).

You will probably find that hiring graduates, nondegree students, summer interns, and part-time employees is encouraged.

Comment: "In my groups I have several promising students to whom I would like to offer a job **after the course ends**."  So I don't think he stands to be accused of poaching. But it does happen in some *métiers* like gaming software development where a student who's clearly good enough to be a useful employee is made an offer he/she can't refuse and abandons the course being pursued. This clearly deprives the college of revenue but more importantly undermines its credibility in providing adequate or desirable training for work.

Comment: @Trunk "After the course ends" presumably means the specific course term in which OP is teaching them, not their entire "course of study"/degree program. So if they took a job it could be after *this course* but well before graduation, if this is not their final term.

Comment: Maybe, nanoman. But Mael needs to clarify that.

Comment: Yes, "course" means different things in different places.

Comment: @Trunk Yeah, +nanoman is right. I was thinking of offering them a job after *my* course. But I see your point, and I have to conclude it's a valid one. Thank you.

Comment: OP did mention afterwards that this would be a summer job, which I would assume would be highly encouraged by all parties involved.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, the question has changed.

Answer (score 11):

The University likes it when their students get jobs, and invites industry representatives precisely for that purpose (but usually less directly -- "we'd like your grads to know more X" or "we definitely want to send people to their job faire"). They won't get mad you hired their grads too quickly.

But you want to avoid the *appearance* of impropriety. You don't want other students saying some people only got A's because they were working for you, or that you spent too much class time looking for hires. You don't want your University contact person to get a bad impression. So simply encourage those students to apply at your company, listing you as a reference. Keeps it at arms length. And sure, sure, ask your contact person at the U, or maybe an advisor.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a (former) student who was hired by the company of my adjunct professor. I was taking a PHP web design course at a community college in the US. He informed the entire class that his company was hiring and encouraged us to apply. He didn't single me out specifically, and he also didn't have any outward say in the recruitment, like telling people they'd be great for the job or that they'd get hired for sure.

I interviewed with people completely unrelated to him and was offered the job independent of any grading, etc that would have happened for the course. It was the semester that I was supposed to graduate from the college, so I was allowed to finish all my courses and work full time around that.

Once I was hired, my professor stayed slightly distant at the job until I had finished his course, at which point we became good friends and he's now my personnel manager. As long as there's a clear distinction between the company and the professor and they aren't involved in the hiring process, I think it's a great opportunity for students.

Comment: Sounds like a professional guy. You can be very sure that his word was responsible for 90% of the final hiring decision.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in New Zealand. I was a guest lecturer at a university and a representative of industry (government actually.)

What happened was that I had a good student who was looking for a job, and I encouraged him to apply for a job in my company (government department) after the course ended.

Perhaps I should note that he was actually a postdoc who was taking courses because he was finding it hard to get a job and considering a transition to industry, so he was a bit more mature than the average student.

(The New Zealand situation is maybe a bit different though, since we have an extreme nepotism problem, so everyone is happy that we hired someone good rather than the boss's nephew!)

Answer (score -1):

You should not worry about the university so much as worry about your organization's personnel manager and your own record for hiring good staff.

Most EU countries have employment law stating that positions (part- or full-time) must be fairly advertised internally, locally and nationally prior to their being offered internationally - though in exceptional cases like rare skills they may be advertised nationally (e.g. national newspaper) and internationally (e.g. *New Scientist*)  simultaneously.

The jobs at issue here are either summer/sandwich internships or else graduate-level trainee positions. It's possible existing staff at the employer organization may have sons/daughters who would be candidates for such jobs - you cannot afford to vex these staff by denying their children their right to apply. Then there are student/graduate candidates from other local or national colleges who also have a right to apply - though naturally the non-locals would be disadvantaged if they have to live away from home.

Now, there's nothing wrong with inviting students to apply for jobs at your organization as long as they are aware that they are not the sole candidates and appointments are made on broad merit grounds.

But the dilemma you face is here. On the one hand, if you do right educationally and not mention jobs till the end of the course/exams then you stand to miss some of the students you'd like to hire - they may have committed to working elsewhere, going abroad, etc in the meantime. On the other hand, if you advise all (and it must be **all** to avoid accusations of "creaming" being made to university management) students of possible internships/jobs, then this will affect both student motivation and cooperation between students - some students will cut the professional/social throats of others just for a job, it's a fact.

Personally, I think the best thing is for you to keep silent on jobs till after your educational commitment is complete but occasionally (at suitable points of lectures or in discussing course work) making the point that **employers generally** like certain virtues in candidates like cooperation with people you may not like socially, willingness to give some extra time to a sticky problem, initiative, honest endeavour, thinking outside the box, good design, clear communication, appreciation of human diversity, etc, etc. The real good ones will take some of this aboard, the what's-in-it-for-me types will turn a deaf ear.

I think that this approach - despite the risk of losing an occasional coveted candidate - is fairest to the employing organization, the student candidates, the university's reputation and - eventually in the long run - your own judgement and reputation.

Note too that those who shine in a university environment may not stand out so much in other working environments: they may be less motivated in an all-ages situation, or may find the stop/start tempo hard to take or may not be motivated by working for the company's reputation instead than their own. Were you to proceed hastily and unilaterally "book" a student for an internship where he/she disappoints then some people in your own company will note this - formally and informally.

Comment: Where does the international angle come from? While it's true that it's harder to hire people who don't have a work permit, I don't see why this would apply here - presumably the students are mostly local. Working in Germany and Austria we've *absolutely* hired people without ever even creating an official job offer and that'd be the first time I ever hear that that would be illegal. What law are you thinking of that requires such stringent rules? I only know of such requirements for government jobs.

Comment: This isn't just about the law - though failure to advertise a position internally can lead to current employees taking a claim on that basis. It is about the **employers own personnel policies and practices**, something the personnel management division of the company has responsibility for and therefore authority upon: they have the final say on every appointment and dismissal. It is common enough that employers would commit to advertising all relevant vacancies internally first. The local aspect is for the company's own convenience. The national aspect due to industrial relations agreements.

Comment: But you state at the start "Most EU countries have *employment law* that positions (part- or full-time) must be fairly advertised internally, locally and nationally", which is very different from "yeah it makes sense for the company to do so". I'm not aware of any such laws which is why I was asking about an example. I mean I've been involved in hiring people in Austria and I'd imagine our lawyers would've had something to say about blatantly illegal behavior on our part. And if such a law really existed wouldn't hiring people that apply on their own without a job advert also be illegal?

Comment: So yeah I think you're confusing this with the more stringent requirement for government jobs (or the special rules when hiring people without an existing work permit) where such rules do indeed exist. But I may be wrong - which is why I was asking about an example :)

Comment: There is law that directly prohibits something and there is law that indirectly prohibits it via exposure to claims. Anti-discrimination law exists within employment law. It is in part for avoiding such challenges that companies tend to establish recruitment and selection processes that they will adhere to. This is not simply about government jobs, it is about all jobs except those ones like domestic servants, lab attendants, etc where employers may choose people more freely. That said, some people will go ahead and hire whom they want. But you should check if doing so exposes you to a claim.

Comment: (This is interesting, so I'll post this as a question law SE tonight I think). Is there any example of a successful law suit on this? Discrimination is only illegal if you discriminate against certain protected classes as I understand it and "Not hired because could not apply" isn't one, so what would be illegal there?

Comment: "Not hired because not told of vacancy" is more like it. To me that is clear discrimination. How can anyone get a chance to offer their skills when they are simple excluded from the outset ? A cast-iron case, you might say.

Comment: Sure that's discrimination. But discrimination is **not** illegal. It's only illegal if you discriminate against someone based on a protected class (gender, age, religion,..). Who was discriminated based on which protected class here?

Comment: Looks like you are right in relation to anti-discrimination. Likewise with Employment Equality Acts. We'd better say no more here owing to moderator comment.

Comment: @Trunk: No moderator to be seen here (no diamond icons), just users. But the system itself will notice a very long comment chain. A moderator might step in and remove these comments; it's up to you if you want to use these comments to improve your answer as you see fit.

Comment: @Voo  You have raised some interesting points. It is astonishing if there is no legal protection to a person's right to apply for jobs being denied through non-advertisement of jobs. I often wondered how some college presidents pushed through "new blood" policies for hiring new lecturers since large employers have to tread carefully around staff unions, custom & practice, etc. Then there's the "self-selection" of candidates for a small business: they take the risk of joining a start-up and thus become heir apparents for every promotion available to and achievable by them.

Comment: Here are some straight answers on the above matter https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64390/allowable-discrimination-for-jobs